# Getting function parameters and variables names and values from decorated function

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators

It is possible to make logger decorator print variable names and values of the decorated funcion

```
def logger(f):
  def inner(*args):
    f(*args)
    print(vars())
  return inner 

@logger
def add(a,b):
  c = 5
  d = a + b +c
  return d

add(1,2)
```

Ouput :

```
{'args': (1, 2)}
```

Expected output:

```
{'d': 8, 'c': 5, 'b': 2, 'a': 1}
```

Comment: It's not that simple.  Your `logger` function has to reach inside `f` to report the variable values; they aren't at the same scope level.  Perhaps you could read up a little on how to reach into the run-time stack.  Even then, you will want `add` to invoke `vars` to get the run-time state of the variables.  That information exists only while `add` is running.

Comment: been googling and havent realy found anything , you got any ressources to learn about reaching run-time stack?

Comment: In theory this might be possible in CPython by modifying the bytecode to make a new function object, but it would be messy. The problem is you can only get the local variables from the function's stack frame, but the only way to get access to that would be from inside the function itself, so the function needs to be changed to either retain a copy of the stack frame or otherwise a dictionary of its local variables somehow.

Comment: There may well be an alternative to what you want to do - I'm guessing you want this decorator for the purpose of debugging functions, so perhaps an existing debugger will do what you want, perhaps an interactive visualisation tool like [Python Tutor](http://pythontutor.com/) will do what you want, or perhaps the [`pdb`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html) API can be leveraged to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the `inspect` module to get information about the arguments passed to the function, or you can read all of the function's local variables from `func.__code__.co_varnames`.

For example:

```
import inspect


def logger(f):
  def inner(*args):
    print(f'signature: {inspect.signature(f)}')
    print(f'variables: {f.__code__.co_varnames}')
    return f(*args)
  return inner 


@logger
def add(a,b):
  c = 5
  d = a + b +c
  return d
```

Result:

```
>>> add(4,5)
signature: (a, b)
variables: ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
14
```

There is no way to get the values of the internal variables, but you can get the values of the arguments:

```
def logger(f):
  def inner(*args):
    print(f'signature: {inspect.signature(f).bind(*args)}')
    return f(*args)
  return inner
```

Result:

```
>>> add(9,10)
signature: <BoundArguments (a=9, b=10)>
24
```

Note that both `Signature` and `BoundArguments` have additional information you can get if you dig deeper into them. See [`inspect` module docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) for more info.

Comment: This prints the names of the variables, but not their values.

Comment: Exactly i already tried that but i only get names wihout values

Comment: @kaya3 True, I added that now.

Comment: @Yefet See the last example to get the argument's values.

Comment: *"There is no way to get the values of the internal variables"* - this isn't really true, there are some ways that make this possible, they're just quite messy.

Comment: @kaya3 There is no way to do it! The internal variables may be changing during the execution, for example if you have `a+=1; a+=1; a+=1` inside the function. Which value would then be the value of `a`? An internal variable simply has no value when you are outside the function. And the decorator is _outside_. It is executing both before and after, but not during the function's execution. Even if you made it execute within, at which place within the function would that be?

Comment: If there were really no way to do it then [Python tutor](http://pythontutor.com/) would not exist, for example.

Comment: @kaya3 PYthon tutor is not a decorator!The problem is not technical, but logical. The request makes no sense.

Comment: Yes, but it *does* get the values of a function's local variables, proving that it is possible to do so. One possibility to make a decorator do it is to create a new function object with a modified version of the original function's bytecode, which does the same as the original function but also leaks a reference to its own stack frame to the outer function.

Comment: @kaya3L Python tutor is stepping through the code in real time, like a debugger. The state of local variables can not generally be known prior to execution, nor after execution which are the only times that the decorator has access to the decorated function. I guess that it would be possible to have the decorator behave like a debugger and run the function's code itself, but that seems like overkill for the purposes of logging a function's internal state.

Comment: Yes, Python tutor is effectively uses a debugger under the hood; the `pdb` module gives programmatic access to a debugger and could perfectly well be used by a decorator. A decorator takes a function and returns a function, generally not the same one; since the function it returns is one that the decorator creates itself, then it can give itself whatever access it needs, so long as the interpreter provides a mechanism to do so. The interpreter does actually provide some such mechanisms.

Comment: The fact that local variables can take different values during the function's execution hardly shows that it is impossible; it just shows that you need to choose a time (e.g. when the function returns) and output their values at that time. As it happens, if you keep a reference to a stack frame after a function completes, the stack frame retains the values that the local variables had when the function completed.

Comment: "It would be possible but that seems like overkill" is a rather different - and contradictory statement - to "there is no way".

Comment: @kaya3: OK, I believe you, but please show us. Please add an answer that shows how to keep a reference to a function's stack frame that would allow inspection after the function returns. It sounds feasible.

Comment: I think it would take too much of my time to get a proof of concept working, but I might take up the project later out of curiousity. If I do then I will write an answer.

Comment: @kaya3L I didn't say that it was impossible. I said that I though it prohibitively expensive. That's what I meant by overkill. Anyway, it's an interesting problem and I'd like to see some code.

Comment: Yes, getting the "last values" of the internal variables would be a well defined task and theoretically possible within one Python implementation, since what happens under the hood is not defined by the language. That may or may not be what the OP asked for, though.

Comment: @kaya3: yes, writing the code would be overkill for the purposes of answering this question :)

Comment: @mhawke talking about "Python tutor is stepping through the code in real time, like a debugger", its not possible to make a decorator act that way? for exmple print variable and value and timestamp , so we can have same value get repeated by different timestamp

Comment: @YefetL yes, it is possible, but do you really want to introduce an additional layer of execution for what appears to be debugging purposes. I would look to the [`logging`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html?highlight=logging#module-logging) module and add logging to those (probably few) functions that require such detailed logging.

Comment: @Yefet: ot look at kaya3's suggestion to somehow maintain a reference to the function so that it can be inspected after execution.